# Error in Knitting an .Rmd file in RStudio

Tags: html, r, knitr

I am trying to knit an RMD file to output as HTML format. However, I get this error message and have no idea what is causing it to occur I have taken a screenshot of the image below:

[image]

What does this mean?

Also, I notice that my output is generated in .txt format. How do I solve this issue and get the .Rmd file to run successfully?

Comment: Could you please post some of your rmd file so there is a minimum example?

Comment: I found the solution @IanWesley. Thanks for the attempt to help though

Answer (score -2):

I solved the issue.

The issue was not importing the "knitr" package. Also, there is code cells or rather known as code chunks in R studio. This chunk needs to be run and be present within the RMD file. This code is actually by default given at the top of a page when opening a new RMD file.

Here is the code below:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

This bit of code should not be deleted, as it is the line of code that knits the .Rmd file.

Comment: That chunk does not need to be there. You can delete that chunk and everything should work just fine.  What it does is set all of the chunk options to echo = true, which means the code will show when you knit the file.